# Concatening an array value to SQL Query Error

Tags: php, sql

I am obtaining some values from an array and making a match against these values in an SQL Query.

The code for this is as follows:

```
  foreach($files as $ex){

      $search = substr($ex,3,4);

  $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT `pdb_code` FROM pdb WHERE `pdb_code` <> ' .$search. ' LIMIT 6';

  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $pdb[] = $row['pdb_code'];
  } 
}
```

The issue that I am having is

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'LIMIT 6' at line 1

Please help.. Thanks

Comment: Haven't you forgot quotes?

Comment: You need to wrap your `$seach` in to quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Add quotes:

```
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT `pdb_code` FROM pdb WHERE `pdb_code` <> "' .$search. '" LIMIT 6';
```

Comment: Thanks Dhara Parmar

Answer (score 0):

As you are writing query in single quote and printing the variable in single quote again so when you will print this query you see the query ends like this:

```
    'SELECT DISTINCT `pdb_code` FROM pdb WHERE `pdb_code` <> '
```

so to make it read all the way you have to enclose you variable in double quotes.. i hope this description will help. you can write it like any of these..

```
    'SELECT xyz FROM abc WHERE xyz = "'.$abc.'" ';
```

OR

```
    "SELECT xyz FROM abc WHERE xyz = '.$abc.'"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot LaviJ

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your query by putting it in double quotes:

Instead this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT `pdb_code` FROM pdb WHERE `pdb_code` <> ' .$search. ' LIMIT 6';
```

Try this :

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `pdb_code` FROM pdb WHERE `pdb_code` <> ' .$search. ' LIMIT 6";
```

Comment: Thank you official

Answer (score 0):

Please, don't use mysql_query() function - it is deprecated in php < php7 and since php7 it is removed. The best practice for now is to use PDO. If You must doing this in old way, use mysqli_query.

In my opinion, the best thing You can do is the following:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1', 'username', 'password');
$statement = $db->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT `pdb_code` FROM pdb WHERE `pdb_code` <> :search LIMIT 6');
$statement->execute([':search' => $search]);
$resultAsAnArray = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```